# Why std::list is consuming all memory in insertion

Tags: c++, stdlist

I have this struct:

```
struct Node {
    list<int> path;
    int cost;

    Node(int cost = 0) {
        this->cost = cost;
    }

    Node(const Node &other, int newNode, int cost) {
        path = other.path;
        path.push_back(newNode);
        this->cost = other.cost + cost;
    }

    bool operator>(const Node &rsh) const {
        return cost > rsh.cost;
    }
};
```

and this line of code

```
Node newNode(node, *i, cost);
```

where node is other Node object with cost = 0 and path contains one element: 0.
*i = 1 and cost = 1
The problem is that when this code is running the program starts consuming more and more memory until all memory in my pc is consumed and my computer freezes.
Using the debugger I discover the problem is in this line

```
path.push_back(newNode);
```

When the program reaches this line it consumes all RAM and if I replace the path type from list to vector, the problem does not occur.

Any ideas of why is this happening?

This is all the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <queue>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

struct Node {
    list<int> path;
    int cost;

    Node(int cost = 0) {
        this->cost = cost;
    }

    Node(const Node &other, int newNode, int cost) {
        path = other.path;
        path.push_back(newNode);
        this->cost = other.cost + cost;
    }

    bool operator>(const Node &rsh) const {
        return cost > rsh.cost;
    }
};

Node result;

class Graph {
    uint size;
    vector<int> *adjacents;
    vector<int> *weights;

public:
    Graph(uint size);
    ~Graph();

    void addEdge(int v1, int v2, int weight);
    bool UCF(int start, int target);
    void displayPath(const Node &node);
};

Graph::Graph(uint size) {
    this->size = size;
    adjacents = new vector<int>[size];
    weights = new vector<int>[size];
}

Graph::~Graph() {
    delete[] adjacents;
    delete[] weights;
}

void Graph::addEdge(int v1, int v2, int weight) {
    adjacents[v1].push_back(v2);
    weights[v1].push_back(weight);

//    non-directed graph
//    adj[v2].push_back(v1);
//    weights[v2].push_back(weight);
}

bool Graph::UCF(int start, int target) {

    priority_queue<Node, vector<Node>, greater<Node>> queue;
    Node startNode(0);
    startNode.path.push_back(start);
    queue.push(startNode);

    while (!queue.empty()) {
        const Node &node = queue.top();
        queue.pop();

        int current = node.path.back();

        if (current == target) {
            result = node;
            return true;
        } else {
            const vector<int> &adj = adjacents[current];
            uint pos = 0;

            for (auto i = adj.begin(); i != adj.end(); ++i) {
                int cost = weights[current][pos];
                Node newNode(node, *i, cost);
                queue.push(newNode);

                ++pos;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}

void Graph::displayPath(const Node &node) {
    cout << "Path: ";
    for (auto i = node.path.begin(); i != node.path.end(); ++i) {
        cout << "->" << *i;
    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Path lenght: " << node.cost;
}

int main() {

    uint vertices = 6;

    Graph graph(vertices);

    graph.addEdge(0, 1, 1);
    graph.addEdge(0, 5, 12);
    graph.addEdge(1, 2, 3);
    graph.addEdge(1, 3, 1);
    graph.addEdge(2, 4, 3);
    graph.addEdge(3, 4, 1);
    graph.addEdge(3, 5, 2);
    graph.addEdge(4, 5, 3);

    int start = 0, end = 5;

    if (graph.UCF(start, end)) {
        cout << "Found!" << endl;
        graph.displayPath(result);
    } else {
        cout << "Not found!" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of how you are using this `struct` and also indicate how many of these `Node`s you are creating. It copies the list in each node so this could be the issue.

Comment: It is the first iteration so node, and newNode are the first Node objects that are created, I will edit so I include the function

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: No, that is still not minimal and complete.  You just posted some code in the middle of a class (we don't even know if that class instance is valid).  We also don't know when, where, how that code is used, what data is used, etc.

Comment: `const vector<int> &adj = adjacents[current];`  --  This is when you should start using `at()` instead of `[ ]` to access your elements.  How are you certain that `current` is within bounds?  I see no checks for this except for faith that the index is within bounds.  Using `at()` will enforce that the index is within bounds, else a `out_of_range` exception will be thrown.

Comment: I use the debugger and all the values are good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These lines of code:

```
    const Node &node = queue.top();
    queue.pop();
```

Consider what `node` is referring to after you have called `pop`

Comment: I change the const reference to copy assigment `Node node = queue.top();` and it works very well, thanks